# linux device tree node names and labels duplicated in include files

Tags: linux

In the linux kernel device tree documentation for [pinctrl-single binding](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/pinctrl-single.txt) I find this syntax in the example:

```
/* SoC common file */

/* first controller instance for pins in core domain */
pmx_core: pinmux@4a100040 {
...

/* board specific .dts file */

&pmx_core {
...
```

The `pmx_core` label appears in the SoC common file (I assume this is an include file with .dtsi extension) and in the board specific .dts file.

What does the & in front of the pmx_core label mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually used to "append" devices to a node defined in another file.

In your case, you will likely find nodes underneath your &pmx_core node which are attached ot the pmx_core defined in the SoC common file.

Comment: to make this work, it must be that labels are needfully unique, or it will mess up, right?